# Warning: spawn ENOENT Use with Grunt sass task

Tags: macos, sass, gruntjs, osx-yosemite, osx-yosemite-beta

I recently downloaded OSX Yosemite and now grunt-contrib-sass is not working and I am getting the error:

```
Running "sass:dist" (sass) task
Warning: spawn ENOENT Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I'm not a grunt expert, do I need to reinstall any plugins or something else? I'm happy to provide any other information if needed. Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like you need to install sass: `gem install sass` or http://sass-lang.com/install `Warning: spawn ENOENT` means node is trying to spawn a process that doesn't exist.

Comment: I had to use `sudo gem install sass` but it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes this error in grunt-contrib-compass after update to Yosemite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423705/what-causes-this-error-in-grunt-contrib-compass-after-update-to-yosemite)

Answer (score 34):

Adding it as an answer here from comments above for posterity.

That error usually means Sass isn't installed. Run `gem install sass` to install it.

For me, it kept failing to install, so ran `gem install sass --debug --backtrace --verbose` and that fixed the `no implicit conversion of nil into String (TypeError)` install error.

Comment: `gem install sass` also worked for me doing a totally different thing (connecting steroids^2 to an app) while getting this ENOENT error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that running `compass` directly threw an exception, so I uninstalled compass and reinstalled it (making sure to delete all compass binaries on `PATH`) and that fixed it.