# What causes this error in grunt-contrib-compass after update to Yosemite?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman, osx-yosemite, grunt-contrib-sass

I am using Yeoman.  After upgrading to Yosemite, the tasks `grunt server` and `grunt build` throw this error:

```
/Users/rogerfuentes/Documents/Web/Kelios/test/node_modules/grunt-contrib-compass/node_modules/tmp/lib/tmp.js:261
throw err;
        ^
Error: spawn ENOENT
    at errnoException (child_process.js:1001:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:792:34)
```

What is causing this error, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an answer, but I'll use your experience as advice and I'll wait to install.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you run compass on the terminal window, you will see the following error:

> -bash: /usr/bin/compass: /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

If you go to the `/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework`, you will see the installation has updated Ruby version to 2.0. That's why running the compass fails, because there is no ruby 1.8 anymore.

The solution is to re-install compass on Yosemite by running:

```
xcode-select --install
sudo gem update --system
sudo gem install compass
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying an otherwise opaque error message :)

Comment: Add .RB and .RBW to the Variable Value list as %PATHEXT%;.RB;.RBW and click OK.