# Error: "compass:dist" Fatal error: spawn /usr/bin/compass ENOENT

Tags: build, gruntjs, compass

Guys, I'm generating build my application with the grunt, it uses the compass.
I set some variables:

```
export GEM_PATH =/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2@global
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.2/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/bin;
export PATH=$PATH:$GEM_PATH;
export PATH=$PATH:node_modules/grunt-cli/bin;
```

and perform the build grunt.
The following Fatal error is :

4mRunning "compass:dist" (compass) task[24m
31mFatal error: spawn /usr/bin/compass ENOENT[39m

Could someone help me with this problem?

Thank

Comment: There's a similar error appearing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26423705/what-causes-this-error-in-grunt-contrib-compass-after-update-to-yosemite

Maybe that could be of help to you

Answer (score 27):

I have had this issue after updating to EL Capital.

The following thread has yielded positive results. As I am unsure about your local environment, here's the link so that you can go through a few solutions:
https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/1768

Here's what solved it for me:

```
brew install ruby
sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin compass
```

Comment: same happened to me after upgrading to high sierra, and the above command to install compass again fixed the issue.

Comment: This fix the problem with high sierra, thanks, you made my day

Comment: Jakub Wawszczyk is right this was the right answer to my issue as well, but I had to install the command line xcode developer tools in order to install ruby and then the gem.

Comment: Works with the same issue after upgrading to macOS Catalina as well.